# Attempted import error: 'Grid' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm getting this error
I have created a new project using npx-create-react-app and then followed the instructions written down here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction
I've installed using: `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`.
Then took the CDN and copying it to my index.html

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
<link
**rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
crossorigin="anonymous"
/>**
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

Then have imported:

```
import React from 'react';
import  {Grid}  from 'react-bootstrap';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <Grid className ="purchase-card">
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried searching Google for a solution and variations of importing (import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button' for example) and I cannot seem to find the issue causing this.

Comment: Is `Grid` even a `react-bootstrap` component? I don't see any reference to it in the docs?

Comment: This may be your issue: [grid was renamed to container](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/migrating/#grid)

Answer (score 14):

Grid was renamed to Container [as you can see here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/migrating/)